# how to use carbon subDays() with a column value

Tags: mysql, laravel, php-carbon

How can I use the Carbon `subDays()` function with a column value?

```
public function getExpiredClaims(): array
{

    $ss = $this->connection->table('claim')->selectRaw('claim.id as id, project.claim_expiry_sla as expiry_sla,
         (select datetime from claim_status_history 
         where claim_status_history.claim_id_binary = claim.id_binary 
         order by insert_id desc limit 1)
        as status_last_changed_at')->join('promotion', function ($join) {
            $join->on(DB::raw("UNHEX(REPLACE(promotion.id, '-', ''))"), '=', 'claim.promotion_id_binary');
        })->join('project', 'project.id', '=', 'promotion.project_id')->where('claim.cached_status',
            ClaimStatus::AWAITING_INFORMATION())->having('status_last_changed_at', '<=',
            $this->clock->now()->subDays(`project.claim_expiry_sla`))->where('platform',
            Platform::OPIA_CLOUD())->limit(1000)->get()->toArray();

    return $ss;
}
```

While running tests, it shows the project.claim_expiry_sla: not found. I don't want to use MySQL.

```
->havingRaw('`status_last_changed_at` \<= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL `expiry_sla` DAY)') ,
```

I need to use subtract project.claim_expiry_sla days from clock interface. How can i do this ??

I tried with

```
->having('status_last_changed_at', '<=', $this->clock->now()->subDays(DB::raw(`project.claim_expiry_sla`)))
```

but this won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution does not work because `project.claim_expiry_sla` is just a string at this point, it's not yet a column value, it will only be a date value when MySQL runs the query, by MySQL execute only SQL code, at this point it's to late to invoke your clock or whatever from PHP world.

However you can just pass the date from your clock as a value so MySQL can actually use it. You're indeed correct that it's best to never use `NOW()` so you don't rely on current clock from your database and can mock it.

```php
->havingRaw(
    '`status_last_changed_at` <= DATE_SUB(:now, INTERVAL `expiry_sla` DAY)',
    ['now' => $this->clock->now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u')]
)
```